# Adding multiple div boxes under each other and looping

Tags: php, html, css, positioning

I'm looking to create a rating website however currently I'm struggling to get them to look like so: [Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLmog.png)

Currently I have this problem:

[Current Position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkqK2.png)

Here is my html/php:

```
<div id="center">
<?php
  for ($i = 0; $i<3; $i++) {
    ?><div class="floating-box">No Content</div>
    <div class="floating-boxsmall">No Content</div>
    <?php
  }
?>
```

Here is my relevant CSS:

```
   #center {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 30%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -150px;
}

.floating-box {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #0076be;  
}
.floating-boxsmall {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #0076be;  
}
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go ahead and wrap your items in a container like so:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i<3; $i++) { ?>
  <div class="floating-item">
    <div class="floating-box">No Content</div>
    <div class="floating-boxsmall">No Content</div>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Remove the float from `box` and `boxsmall` and add it to `floating-item` instead.

```
#center {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -150px;
}

.floating-item {
  float: left;
}

.floating-box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #0076be;  
}

.floating-boxsmall {
  width: 150px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #0076be;  
}
```

And to save you from future headaches, don't forget to clear your items:

http://learnlayout.com/clearfix.html

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `.floating-box` and `.floating-boxsmall` with a parent container:

```
.parent{
  width: 150px;
  margin:10px;
  float:left;
}
```

Then in your child containers, remove floating and eventually left/right margin because you are assigning them in your parent container:

```
.floating-boxsmall{
  float:left;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.floating-box{
  float:none;
  margin:0px; 
}
```

**IN YOUR PHP:**

```
<?php
  for ($i = 0; $i<3; $i++) {?>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="floating-box">No Content</div>
      <div class="floating-boxsmall">No Content</div>
    </div>
    <?php
  }
?>
```

Haven't tested this but it should work. You need a parent container for sure. Play with it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#center{

  margin:0px auto;

}

.floating-box, .floating-boxsmall{
 display:block;
 float:left;
  margin:10px 5px;
  background-color:#ccc;
  text-align:center;  
  padding:20px;

}

.floating-box{
  min-height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="center">
<div class="floating-box">No Content</div>
    <div class="floating-boxsmall">No Content</div>
    <div class="floating-box">No Content</div>
    <div class="floating-boxsmall">No Content</div>
    <div class="floating-box">No Content</div>
    <div class="floating-boxsmall">No Content</div>
    </div>
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zooxstudio/g5w7kp9v/)